# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'metasploit-framework'.: Permission denied

Tags: software-installation, permissions, git

I am following this guide.

I am doing this:

```
cd /opt
git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git
cd metasploit-framework
```

When I am doing :

```
git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git
```

I am getting the following error :

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'metasploit-framework'.: Permission denied
```

Comment: Link for the following guide is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in the terminal to open a new terminal session as root, so that you get permission to run the commands:

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to git clone into the `/opt` directory and don't have privileges.

Use:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git
```

Alternately git clone into your home directory then if you need to `make` the executable or install just invoke your superuser privileges then with sudo.